# AWS RDS Aurora Reader Replication to External MySql Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to use AWS aurora replica as a master for external MySQL instance.

I have created an aurora instance and a read replica with BinLog enabled DB cluster parameter.

Replication from writer is working fine but I am not able to see bin_log parameter ON for read replica.

Is there any way by which we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried contacting AWS to achieve this and I got to know that It is not possible to replicate from the Aurora Replica to the external mysql instance.

For replication, we need to turn off the read-only or turn on GTID so that we can setup Master-Master replication but at the moment in aurora all the nodes will read the data from the same cluster volume and only write node can perform writes on the database. Because of this it is not possible to disable the read_only option in Aurora replica. Also GTID replication is not currently supported in RDS Aurora.

Comment: Is this information still up to date? The documentation says it is possible: Because Amazon Aurora MySQL is compatible with MySQL, you can set up replication between a MySQL database and an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster. You can set up replication where your Aurora MySQL DB cluster is the replication master or the replica, and you can replicate with an Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance, a MySQL database external to Amazon RDS, or another Aurora MySQL DB cluster. If you use the reader endpoint of the cluster, you would be reading from (a random) replica instance, right?

Answer (score 0):

The information in the answer is out-of-date:

Here's how to do replication from Aurora to an external MySQL instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html

Because that page covers all the combinations of Aurora source, Aurora destination, RDS MySQL destination, external MySQL destination, the instructions can have a lot of IF-THEN branching. But it can be done.

GTID replication support came later: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/mysql-replication-gtid.html

The crucial thing to understand is that with binlog replication, it's the writer instance that's producing the binlogs. So it's the writer instance that would always be the source of binlog replication. What used to be called the "Aurora replicas" have nothing to do with binlogs. They get their changes from the writer instance by an entirely different low-overhead, low-latency mechanism. That's why AWS prefers to call them "reader instances" instead of replicas now, so they don't get mixed up in discussions of binlog replication.